# What does Newt say at the end of Aliens?

Tags: dialogue, aliens

At the very end of Aliens. After Ripley has blown the queen alien out the airlock, and she climbs up over the edge of the airlock door. Newt jumps into her arms and says something.

It sounds either like "Hold me" or "Mommy".

They both sound correct after listening to it a few times, but it seems more relevant to Ripley's character if she actually said "Mommy".

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The line is indeed `Mommy`, as you can see from [the script](http://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Aliens.html) in scene 199:

[image: Script excerpt from Aliens]

Comment: Yep - this scene is all the stronger if you've watched the Director's Cut where we see Ellen on the space station mourning the loss of her own daughter.

Comment: @Nobby exactly, that was the version I was watching. So sad that this connection between Newt and Ripley is not continued in the series.